# Css rotation not applied in android (phonegap)

Tags: android, css, cordova, rotation

I'm building an app for android in phonegap and I have an issue with rotating divs with css.
I have found a similar question here:
[CSS rotation not applied in Android 4.0 webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359543/css-rotation-not-applied-in-android-4-0-webview/)

I have 2 android devices on which I can test my app. The first one is a Sony Xperia U with `android 4.0.4`. On this device the app works perfectly.

The other device is an HTC Desire with `android 2.3.5`. This device has a problem with the css rotation. When the page loads, the image is rotated correclty but immediately  turns back to "normal".

The css rule I'm using is - `webkit-transform:rotate(90);` on a normal div.
Could this be a problem with the android version of the system?

I can't get a hold of the problem here, the rotation seems to work on the second device, but only for a second or so.

Any suggestions would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried every possible solution and it only works when I use webkit-transform:rotate(90); twice.

Here's an example of how it did work:

```
<div data-role="content" style="webkit-transform:rotate(90);">
<div style="webkit-transform:rotate(90);">Stuff to rotate</div>
</div>
```

But of course, this did not function properly on ohter devices.

It's not really a solution, but I just excluded any device prior to Android version 4.0.4

Comment: This is a hack not a solution.

Comment: And it should be `90deg` instead of just `90`.

Answer (score 7):

Android 2.x [seems to support CSS3 transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) with the -webkit- prefix, but there's a catch.

This bizarre error comes from a custom set viewport. If you provide a custom viewport for iOS and Android, you must set `user-scalable=yes`. If `user-scalable` is set to **no**, this error appears.

For example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

will work correctly, but something like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

will display incorrectly

Comment: I have set user-scalable=yes but this did not change a thing :)

Comment: Do you have a source for the viewport bug?

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated]**

To prevent your div to turn back to its original state, try to add `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to your div's css :

```
#yourDiv {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Set the last frame as persistent */
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;        /* Set the duration as you wish */
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

If this doesn't work, try to add the final state to `#yourDiv` `-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);`.

If it **still** doesn't work, you could use some JS to add a class to your div at the end of your animation to fix the final state.

Comment: I have tried this and after the rotation, the div adjusts itself to normal again :(

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … }
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

The CSS definition of a media query is at [css3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation)